# Why does this volatile LastRow function not automatically recalculate?

Tags: function, excel, vba

I decided a function for determining the LastRow in excel might save me some time in the long run thus:

```
Function LastRow() As Long
Application.Volatile

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    End With

End Function
```

For the most part this is fine, but I notice that if the actual last cell is merely formatted it will not recalculate the way it does if a value is entered.
It will get it right on a recalculation, but I thought making this volatile would automatically do that.

What have I misunderstood?

**note**
anyone doing something similar, be aware that making this volatile and using ActiveSheet makes it unreliable the moment you activate another sheet, as the function returns the LastRow in that sheet and recalculates. Probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volatile only triggers when a cell is calculated: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213653%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

There is a way to cheat - this is based on the fact that to change a cell, you have to select it first:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

Note that this may break some basic functionality. In the [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213193) article, they comment that their example will break the ability to copy/paste

Comment: Thank You @Sean Cheshire the MSDN article I should have seen myself. I  can see now that formatting in and of itself wouldn't require calculation, as there really aren't input variables entered

Comment: + 1 Yup your are right. Unfortunately the `basic functionality` also includes `UNDO`. The macro will reset the UNDO stack as well.